# Uncaught Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use new react feature hooks in my project. I have updated react version to **16.8.1** however, it gives error

> **Uncaught Error:** Hooks can only be called inside the body of a
>   function component

**package.json**

```
"react": "^16.8.1",
"react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.0",
"react-dev-utils": "^7.0.1",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
```

**index.js**

```
function selectDoc() {
  const [selectedOrg, handleOrgChange] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="select-info">
      <div className="select-showcase">
        <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}>
          <div>With Search</div>
          <Select           
            items={orgsList}
            selectedItem={selectedOrg}
            handleItemChange={handleOrgChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default selectDoc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be correct. However you haven't updated `react-dom` to the same version i.e `16.8.1` as `React` and hence you see this error which is a little misleading at first. Both `react` and `react-dom` should use the same version to be able to use React features correctly.

Run

```
yarn upgrade react-dom@16.8.1
```

to upgrade `react-dom` to `v16.8.1`

If you use `npm` and not yarn, you could run

```
npm update --save react-dom@16.8.1
```

Comment: I am also facing this error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245466/react-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-component

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem actually was not in the component itself, but in the Route.

Instead:

```
<Route path="/login" exact render={MyLoginComponent} />
```

It should be

```
<Route path="/login" exact render={(props) => <MyLoginComponent {...props} />} />
```

Switch from "render" to "component" also works.