# Invalid hook call error: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to add hooks to a subcomponent in a desire to make functions reusable across multiple parent components, I keep getting this `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` error.

This react app was created through `create-react-app` in the usual way.

I've read through https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991, and other stackoverflow answers and haven't found a solution. [Uncaught Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580224/uncaught-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-component) is similar but I'm using the valid versions.

I tried typing `npm ls react` to see if two versions were running but only one version shows:
`-- react@16.8.6`

//**Package.json**

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

//**AdvancedSearch.jsx** -- child component

```
export function HandleSearchFilterChange(props, e) {
   const setAdvancedSearchFilter = useState( props.advancedSearchFilter )[1]; //error triggered here

   useEffect(
      setAdvancedSearchFilter(
         e
      )
   );  
}
```

//**ETablesAndSearch.js** -- parent component

```
import { HandleSearchFilterChange} from '../Components/AdvancedSearch.jsx';

class ETablesAndSearch extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <AdvancedSearch onSearchFilterChange={HandleSearchFilterChange}/>
      )
}
```

*Error Message:* "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"
--at AdvancedSearch.jsx when setting the constant.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, what you're trying to do makes no sense.  Hooks can only be applied on render.  Did you read the "Not supported" section of your first link?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace **class ETablesAndSearch** with a functional component. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your "HandleSearchFilterChange" is not a functional component.

Its just a regular function. As suggested by react "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

There should some html elements to make it as a functional component.